# What is this sax technique called and how is it done?

Tags: technique, saxophone, effects

I recently heard an old Motown hit on the radio called "Shotgun" by Jr. Walker and the Allstars and the Sax part tore me up. It sounds to me like it's seriously overblown, but I don't play sax so I really don't know what I'm talking about. I would like to know if there is a term for this technique and how it is actually accomplished, anyone?

Comment: Are you asking about the "growl" effect specifically, the overall tone of the sax generally, or something else...?

Comment: @ Aaron- Yes, that 'growl', I hear it occasionally in other music too, and I'd like to know how it is done.

Comment: If you want to hear “growl” on steroids check out some Gato Barbieri!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This effect is usually called a "growl". There are two techniques (as explained in the linked video). The one in "Shotgun" is most likely the "'growl' in the back of your throat while playing" technique. The other technique is to hum while playing. When humming, the more consonant the hummed and played pitches, the smoother the growl; the more dissonant, the "growlier".

I suggest you consider one of the many YouTube instructional videos. Like this one, for example (chosen because it's short)...

Websites like TamingTheSaxophone also include [instructions and practice tips](https://tamingthesaxophone.com/saxophone-growl) (humming in this particular case).

These techniques work on most, if not all, wind instruments. (I can personally attest to the trumpet.)

---

EDIT

Growling is an example of a larger set of extended techniques called **multiphonics**. Wikipedia has a very good article [introducing the subject](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiphonic), describing its application to winds, brass, strings, and voice, and providing some history of its use, including a list of composers and musicians who employed the techniques. Based on the article, here are a few historically important uses (videos are timed to an appearance of the technique).

- Early usage in Western Classical music: [Concertino for Horn and Orchestra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concertino_for_Horn_and_Orchestra_(Weber)) in E minor, J188 (Op. 45) (1806, 1815), by [Carl Maria von Weber](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carl_Maria_von_Weber) ([SCORE: IMSLP](https://imslp.simssa.ca/files/imglnks/usimg/0/09/IMSLP396649-PMLP118970-IMSLP_Horn_Concertino_e_moll_horn_in_f.pdf), see m. 168.)

- [Illinois Jacquet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Illinois_Jacquet) popularized the technique in jazz beginning in the 1940s: "[Flying Home](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flying_Home)" (1942), by [Benny Goodman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Benny_Goodman) and [Lionel Hampton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lionel_Hampton).

- [Luciano Berio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luciano_Berio) was a major influence in incorporating multiphonics into twentieth-century Western Classical music. "[Sequenza](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequenza) IX" (1980) for clarinet solo.

Comment: D'you reckon some trumpeters cheat by growling when they're supposed to flutter-tongue?

Comment: @OldBrixtonian Interesting. I've never encountered it, but I have encountered players who find one or the other quite easy or near impossible. The sounds are pretty different, though. Flutter-tonguing is louder and harsher.

Comment: Yes. I've encountered the same players! I don't remember hearing a flutter-tongued sax or a growled clarinet. I wonder if female flautists can growl. Presumably their higher vocal range would interfere better with a flute's notes.

Comment: @OldBrixtonian You've heard [sax flutter-tongue](https://youtu.be/6p3FsA0olbQ?t=18), and you've probably heard [Clarinet growl](https://youtu.be/AfjEAIkWPeE?t=24). But I can't find flute growling. I did find this, though: https://youtube.com/watch?v=g8RRwsro9Gg

Comment: You're right, I HAD heard sax flutterz. (Shorthand!) I had forgotten how different it was from growling, with which I'm very familiar. I've never sax flutterz. Thanks. And that's a fantastic example. That Klezmer growl seems a bit weak. If that's Wil Offermans himself playing I guess that voice staff must be sounding an octave lower, like a tenor's stave. When Jethro Tull sang into his flute it was *in* tune. I wonder what Offermans does differently.

Comment: Fifty years ago wind-players lived in fear of composers who had read Bartolozzi's New Sounds for Woodwind. Perhaps it's the same since Offermans! TVM for the links.